# Forms Fields not rendering on CD server

Tags: sitecore-forms, content-delivery

Our application is on Sitecore 9.0.2 , Azure PaaS

The Forms are working as expected on Standalone and Content Management servers , but few form fields do not render on the website(CD)

The forms and the items containing these forms are available on the web database

The Site is supposed to show this form

[image]

But the Text fields do not render

[image]

We have set IndexAllFields to false , I have tried rebuilding indexes

we are also using Sitecore Forms Extensions Module

Has anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: did you installed form extension modules also on cd servers?

Comment: No , thank you , that may be the issue , Any document or pointers or How to Install the module on CD , i did search for it but could not find anything useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all fields are working except those from the extensions module, so I would assume that the comment from Vlad is correct and you forgot to install the extensions on the CD server. You need to install it there as well.

The Forms Extensions provide a `nodb` version of the package that should be used for installing it on CD servers (this will install the necessary files, but not the database items).

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,  Any document or pointers or How to Install the module on CD , i did search for it but could not find anything useful

Comment: That depends on how you do any deploys to your CDs..  on PAAS I would assume the web deploy package (nodb version) should be added to the deploy templates, but as mentioned that all depends on how you deploy..  You might check http://onelittlespark.bartverdonck.be/part-4-adding-modules-to-your-arm-templates/